# Lagging when switching tabs

Tags: android

I have 3 tab fragments in my activity.
When i swipe through first two there is not lagging, but when i swipe on 3rd tab it lags.

Logcat(i pasted only red lines):

```
2020-01-20 17:35:20.630 645-1072/? E/SDM: DisplayBase::BuildLayerStackStats: LayerStack layer_count: 
4, app_layer_count: 3, gpu_target_index: 3, display type: 0
2020-01-20 17:35:20.630 645-1072/? E/SDM: Strategy::GetNextStrategy: All strategy failed, falling 
back to GPU
2020-01-20 17:35:20.697 645-1072/? E/SDM: DisplayBase::BuildLayerStackStats: LayerStack layer_count: 
4, app_layer_count: 3, gpu_target_index: 3, display type: 0
```

Activity:

```
 TextView mtitle;
ImageView imageView, imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5,imageView6, imageView7,imageView8;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabItem runes,tab2,tab3;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aatrox);


    mtitle = findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
    imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
    imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.imageview4);
    imageView5 = findViewById(R.id.imageview5);
    imageView6 = findViewById(R.id.imageview6);
    imageView7 = findViewById(R.id.imageview7);
    imageView8 = findViewById(R.id.imageview8);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout1);
    runes = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.fragment_tab1);
    tab2 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.fragment_tab2);
    tab3 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.fragment_tab3);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPageratrox);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    pagerAdapter = new PageAdapterAtrox(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Runes");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Items");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("Additional");

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(tab.getPosition() == 1){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(tab.getPosition() == 2){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
}

public void spotlight(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iiGWVhUqLA"));
    startActivity(i);
}
public void biography(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://universe.leagueoflegends.com/en_US/story/champion/aatrox/"));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

3rd fragment(on which is lag starting):

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back3"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".tab3atrox">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:onClick="spotlight"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Spotlight"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-75dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Biography"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:onClick="biography"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview25"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview24"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/yorick"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview23"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/nocturne"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Champion counters"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="Champion spotlight and biography"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview21"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/poppy"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

PageAdapter of activity:

```
public class PageAdapterAtrox extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int nesta;
tab1atrox tab1;
tab2atrox tab2;
tab3atrox tab3;
public PageAdapterAtrox(FragmentManager fm, int num){
    super(fm);
    this.nesta = num;
    tab1 = new tab1atrox();
    tab2 = new tab2atrox();
    tab3 = new tab3atrox();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return  tab1;
        case 1:
            return  tab2;
        case 2:
            return  tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nesta;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

}

Im new to android studio, so i don't know everything.
So if someone can help.

Comment: did you found solution?